# How to imbed video with kWidget from kaltura?

Tags: html, css, kaltura

I am trying to imbed video from kaltura with kWidget but getting error message "No source video was found". My code:

```
<div style="width:100%">
  <h1 style="text-align: center;">This is my title</h1>
  <script src="https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/p/3469953/sp/346995300/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/48037643/partner_id/3469953"></script>
  <div id="kaltura_player_1622276816" style="width: 560px; height: 395px; display: table; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
  <script>
  kWidget.embed({
    "targetId": "kaltura_player_1622276816",
    "wid": "_3469953",
    "uiconf_id": 48037643,
    "flashvars": {},
    "cache_st": 1622276816,
    "entry_id": "1_ez881bg1"
  });
  </script>
</div>
```